# module alias of mli file

Tags: module, ocaml, alias

I have the following situation:

The mli file ds.mli contains just a type declaration:

```
type t = A of int | B of string
```

Now I would like to make an alias to Ds in another module user.ml:

```
module D = Ds
```

On compilation I get the following error message from the linker:

```
$ ocamlc ds.mli user.ml 
File "user.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while linking user.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Ds'
```

If I copy ds.mli to ds.ml and call

```
 $ ocamlc ds.mli ds.ml user.ml
```

The compilation goes through.

Is there a possibility to avoid creating the ds.ml file?

*Remark:* I am aware of the difference between implementation and interface files, but to my knowledge, as long as the interface contains only type definitions, an implementation file is not necessary. Assume we add the following module signature to ds.mli:

```
module T : sig
  type t = C | D
end
```

Then the the definition of bar in user:

```
let bar = function
  | Ds.T.C -> true
  | Ds.T.D -> false
```

compiles without problems via

```
$ ocamlc ds.mli user.ml
```

The expansion of the alias to the signature should not be the problem.

*Edit:* forgot to add ds.ml to the arguments of the second ocamlc call.
*Edit:* added remark about using mli files.

Comment: No, the `mli` file can't actually define anything besides signatures on its own, you need to implement them with an `ml` file

Comment: That's what confuses me - my mli file only contains a type (signature). Referring to it directly via ```match x with | Ds.A i -> i``` works like a charm. Only when I create the module alias, i suddenly need an implementation file for creating ds.cmo .

Comment: If your module type contains only public type signature, it doesn't need an implementation, because there's nothing to implement. But it doesn't mean it can be used as a module either.

Answer (score 4):

`type t = A | B`
within a file `m.ml` is basically the same as
`module M = struct type t = A | B end`.
The same line in a file `m.mli` corresponds to 
`module M : sig type t = A | B end`

The former implements a module. The latter is just a module signature.

A signature can be used to declare types but more commonly it is used to mask some parts of a module implementation to the outside world. The signature never actually implements a module, even if the module only contains type declarations.

A module is like a value, not a type. For instance, modules can be wrapped and manipulated as values in the language ('first-class modules') and can be used as arguments to functors in the module language.

The fact that the function bar works with only the .mli file present is not a contradiction to this; it is a pattern matching on types, and no values of the types are required to exist for defining the function. If you add in user something like `let c = Ds.T.C` then you have constructed such a value, but this has happened in `user.ml`, an implementation file.

Comment: You can use type definitions without implementation files, see my remark in the updated question. The error message means that the linker needs the object file (created from the implementation). I assume there are engineering reasons behind it, coming from the indirection of the alias. But my question is if I can get around this or if I need to live with the duplication as .ml file :-) ( That's why I gave +1 for the answer but don't accept it as solution)

Comment: hmm i don't know how a ds.mli file can suffice. but you could do it the other way around: only create a ds.ml file with the same contents. then the signature is inferred automatically, and you have no duplication?

Comment: That's what i ended up doing.

Answer (score 2):

The line you got it wrong is

```
module D = Ds
```

Here, you're trying to "affect" a module type to a module, and that's not gonna happen.

However, you can do the same with a module type:

```
module type D = module type of Ds
```

Comment: I'm just reading up on module types, but when I replace the Ds in the function bar by D, I get an unbound module error (for D). I guess I need to do something more now?

Comment: Well, it's still a module type, not a module.